# Systems of equations - show there's no distinct solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

A question is as follows - 3 planes,

$\pi_1:x-2y+z=0$;

$\pi_2:3x-z=4$;

$\pi_3:x+y-z=k$;

The question asks for me to show the planes do not intersect at a unique point point. I'm not sure about how to approach this question - what am I aiming to do? What should I eliminate?

Comment: Note that $(x-2y+z)-(3x-z)+2(x+y-z)$ is identically $0$. How you would be expected to do this is course-dependent. Maybe row reduction.  What that means is that unless $0-4+2k=0$ there are no solutions. But if $0-4+2k=0$ there are infinitely many, the whole line of intersection of the first wo planes.

Comment: notice that $\pi_2 - \pi_1$ gives $2x+2y-2z=4$ which is parallel to $\pi_3$

Comment: Start by finding the line of intersection of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$. Then you simply have to show that the resulting line does not intersect $\pi_3$ to show that the planes don't intersect in a single point or that this line lies inside $\pi_3$ hence telling you that the 3 planes intersect in a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1& -2& 1& 0 \\
3& 0& -1& 4 \\
1& 1& -1& k
\end{array}\right).$$
After I do $R_2 \gets -3R_1 + R_2$ and $R_3 \gets -R_1 + R_3$, $R_2 \gets R_3$ and $R_3 \gets -2R_2 + R_3$
I end up with
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1& -2& 1& 0 \\ 0& 3& -2& k \\ 0& 0& 0& 4-2k
\end{array}\right).$$

thus $4-2k=0$ hence $k=2$ and $3y-2z=2$, $1x-2y+z=0$ give  arbitrary values to $y$ you will have values for $z$ and then put it in $1x-2y+z=0$ you will have values for $X$. you see answer isnot unique for $k=2$ and if $k\neq 2$ you wont have any answer.